# How to remove shortcut key created with Ubuntu Tweak?

Tags: shortcut-keys, ubuntu-tweak

Not much time after I installed my ubuntu, I installed ubuntu tweak and added shortcut keys for the applications I used most.

[image: My Ubuntu tweak's shortcut management screen]

However, I wanted to remove a shortcut key and was not able to (the last one). At least, I couldn't figure out a way to do that. I want to reconfigure them using ubuntu's keyboard tool, so I don't mind if I have to delete all shortcut keys from ubuntu tweak. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Double-click the command to display the window shown.

Then press <kbd>ESC</kbd> i.e. the *escape* key and the key will be removed that is displayed as *disabled*

That just leaves the Command itself.  Double click the Command to edit and type *None*.  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the Command will be removed.

Comment: Oh, it worked. But I still think that it should have a more explicit way to do it :)

Comment: suggest pop over to the authors launchpad account and ask just this question - hope this helps.  https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/

Comment: Sorry but this way don't work in 12.04. When you press `ESC` key you get `<Mod2>Escape`

Answer (score 1):

If using <kbd>Escape</kbd> doesn't work, follow most of [the steps by fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/a/108024/22949) but when you get to the part where you would press <kbd>Escape</kbd>, instead press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and that should delete the command/key binding.

Keep in mind though, when you move to the keyboard shortcut system that Ubuntu provides by default, you will not be allowed to use the "Super" key in your shortcut...for some reason it is disabled there. You can apply it as a shortcut but the shortcut will never work unless used via Ubuntu Tweak or CCSM (Compiz).

Answer (score 0):

The "Mod2" key that keep turn ON is actually the Num Lock key (...), as ridiculous as it may seems.

Turn Num Lock off, then press Backspace.  The shortcut will (finally) be deleted.  This also work on Ubuntu 12.04.